# Поиск по многомерному массиву php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Имеется массив такого вида:

```
array (
    "a1" => array (
array(
"test1" => "example1",
"test2" => "example2",
"test3" => "example3",
),
 array( 
"test1" => "example1",
"test2" => "example2",
"test3" => "example3",
),
array( 
"test1" => "example1",
"test2" => "example2",
"test3" => "example3",
)),
    "a2" => array (
array(
"test1" => "example1",
"test2" => "example2",
"test3" => "example3",
),
array( 
"test1" => "example1",
"test2" => "example2",
"tes3t" => "example3",
),
array( 
"test1" => "example1",
"test2" => "example2",
"tes3t" => "example3",
)
);
```

В php новичок. Обычным перебором foreach получилось сделать, но думаю есть более правильный метод. 
Необходимо 3 вещи. 
1) Ключи (а1, а2)

```
 array (a1,a2)
```

2) Из ключа a1 вывести все значения ключей "test1"

```
 array (example1, example1, example1)
```

3) Ключ => значение одного выбранного подмассива a1

```
array ("test1" => "example1",
"test2" => "example2",
"tes3t" => "example3",
)
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Если просто ключи из этого массива, то воспользуйтесь функцией [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
var_dump(array_keys($array));
```

Результат будет:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "a1"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "a2"
}
```

2.Тоже делается просто одной функцией [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) (PHP 5.5+)

```
var_dump(array_column($array['a1'], 'test1'));
```

Результат будет:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "example1"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "example1"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "example1"
}
```

3. Не пойму в чём сложность, просто обращаетесь по ключу и получаете данные.

Comment: Благодарю, все методы мне полностью подходят. Есть еще дополнительный вопрос. Существует ли возможность передать данные из переменной в ключ массива $array ['a1'][0]; В место ['a1'][0]

Comment: @Даниил можно конечно, смотря какие данные, в каком виде они представлены